# How can I iterate a list and walk line by line of file python?

Tags: python

Hi I want read line by line of my file that have coordinates:

(124, 125)

(160, 230)

I need read line by line as (x, y), and take the values and run the refinement of my model. I want to do it, automatically, and no manually.

I have this CODE:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
import sys
import os

old_stdout = sys.stdout
log_file = open ('listprueba.log', "w")
sys.stdout = log_file

with open('list.log') as f:
            for line in f:
                a,b = map(int,line.translate(None,"()[],").split())
                ("x = {}\ny = {}".format(a,b))
                print (a, b)


sys.stdout = old_stdout
log_file.close()

def readfile(filename):
    # opens file, reads contents, and splits it by newline
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        data = f.read().split('\n')

    # iterates through data and converts each string to a tuple
    for item in range(len(data)):
        parentesisi = data[item].find('(')
        coma = data[item].find(',')
        parentesisd = data[item].find(')')
        data[item] = (int(data[item][parentesisi+1:coma]), int(data[item][coma+1:parentesisd]))

    return data

def main():
    for i in readfile('coordinates.log'):
        x=i[0]
        y=i[1]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This part it's ok, it's part of program

```
log.verbose()
env = environ()
class MyLoop(loopmodel):

 # This routine picks the coordinates to be refined by
            def select_loop_atoms(self):
# coordinate insertion
                return selection(self.residue_range(x, y)
```

I have this error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

I just want that read the first line that has the coordinate (124, 125) and sustitute the values in x, y, and run the refinament. Then, return line 2 that has the coordinates (160, 230), and do the same, with respect the lenght of my file.

How can I improve this CODE???

Thanks so much

Comment: what is `list.log` here?

Comment: It's my file with the coordinates (x, y) in form of  [(124, 125)], [(160, 230)]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're trying to transform a line before stripping it, so you're splitting off an empty string somewhere with `str.split`. Try this instead: it's nicer-looking anyway.

```
import ast

with open('path/to/file.txt') as inf:
    for line in inf:
        line = line.strip() # strip the line first
        if not line:
            continue # skip blank lines
        x,y = ast.literal_eval(line)
        # the format (x, y) is a literal tuple. Treat it that way
```

If you want a list of all of the tuples:

```
with open('path/to/file.txt') as inf:
    result = [ast.literal_eval(line) for line in inf if line.strip()]
```